# Use --build-arg value in Dockerfile FROM parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, devops, amazon-ecs

I'm currently using AWS ECR to host my project images and I need the parameter FROM to be dynamic at Dockerfile according to --build-arg sent from the command line. Example:

```
$ docker build --build-args region=us-east-1 .

// Dockerfile
FROM aws.ecr.huge.url.${region}/repo:php-apache
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN echo "@@@"
```

${region} never gets replaced and I get an error saying the image doesn't exist.

If I RUN echo ${region} it works, the problem seems to be with FROM instruction.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

With the introduction of [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/), docker added the ability to provide an `ARG` before the `FROM` line. This will look like:

```
# default to us-east-1
ARG region=us-east-1
FROM aws.ecr.huge.url.${region}/repo:php-apache
```

Note that [`ARG`'s are namespaced](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact). When defined before a `FROM` line, they are available to the `FROM` lines. And within a stage, they are available until the end of that stage. If you need to use an `ARG` in multiple namespaces, you can define it multiple times.

---

**Original answer from before the introduction of multi-stage builds:**

This is not supported as you've found, and as [documented in the variable expansion limitations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement):

> Environment variables are supported by the following list of
>   instructions in the Dockerfile:
>
> - ADD
> - COPY
> - ENV
> - EXPOSE
> - LABEL
> - USER
> - WORKDIR
> - VOLUME
> - STOPSIGNAL
>
> as well as:
>
> - ONBUILD (when combined with one of the supported instructions above)

To workaround this, I suspect you'll need to generate your Dockerfile with an external process first, e.g. with a `sed "s/__region__/$region/" <Dockerfile.in >Dockerfile` command.

Answer (score 0):

ARG is missing in your Dockerfile.
Please try this.

```
$ docker build --build-args region=us-east-1 .
// Dockerfile
ARG region
FROM aws.ecr.huge.url.${region}/repo:php-apache
WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: ```FROM``` needs to be the first (non-comment) command in a dockerfile

Comment: `FROM` instructions support variables that are declared by any `ARG` instructions that occur before the first `FROM`. see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: @lekant that wasn't the case when this answer was first posted. Multi stage builds changed this behavior.